# Django: is possible to find specific object in pagination?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Let say, I want to built a forum with implements the `Thread` and `Comment` concept.. The `Comment` model is `ForeignKey` to the `Thread`.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ....

class Comment(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, ...)
    comment = models.TextField()
    ....
```

1. The ***Detail Thread*** have some ***Comments***
2. The ***Comments at Detail Thread*** using `/?page={number}` for the pagination.

Currently, my comments pagination is work well. But, I have a problem if I want to find the single object of comment.

For example, I have single object of comment with `id=13` found in the `page=3`.

[image: thread]

Here is my `views.py`

```
def thread_detail(request, topic_slug, pk):
    """
    detail thread public view.
    :param `topic_slug` is slug from the topic.
    :param `pk` is id from thread.
    """
    template_name = 'public/thread_detail.html'

    numb_pages = 10
    get_page = request.GET.get('page')
    thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, topic__slug=topic_slug, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(thread=thread).order_by('created')
    ....

    page_obj = PaginatorFBV(comments, numb_pages, get_page).queryset_paginated()
    page_range = PaginatorFBV(comments, numb_pages, get_page).page_numbering()
    comments = page_obj.object_list

    context = {
        'thread': thread,
        'comments': comments,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'page_range': page_range
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

I want to create it with dynamically, for example in my `find_comment_view.py`:

```
def find_comment(request, pk):
    """
    Return redirect to the comment on thread, with current page.
    :param `pk` is pk/id from comment.
    """
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(thread__in=comment.thread)

    # what i should be do here?
```

Thanks so much before..

**UPDATE:**

I try with this one, and work well for me. ***But***, I found another problem if has many pages, eg; thousand of pages.. of course it will take a long time...

```
def find_comment(request, pk):
    """
    Return redirect to the comment on thread, with current page.
    :param `pk` is pk/id from comment.
    """
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(thread=comment.thread).order_by('created')
    thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, pk=comment.thread.pk)

    # Initial `page_obj` to get max numb of pagination.
    items_per_page = 10 # this is same with what we do for `numb_pages = 10` inside `def thread_detail(...)`
    initial_page_obj = PaginatorFBV(comments, items_per_page, 1).queryset_paginated()
    max_numb_pages = initial_page_obj.paginator.num_pages

    for page in range(max_numb_pages):
        page += 1
        page_obj = PaginatorFBV(comments, items_per_page, page).queryset_paginated()
        comment_objects = page_obj.object_list

        # Check the output of `comment_objects`
        # >>> print(comment_objects, page)
        # <QuerySet [<Comment: regina>]> 1
        # <QuerySet [<Comment: beverly>]> 2
        # <QuerySet [<Comment: amy>]> 3
        # <QuerySet [<Comment: hannah>]> 4

        for obj in comment_objects:
            if obj.pk == comment.pk:
                # eg: /thread/20/?page=2#comment-30
                return redirect(
                    ('%s?page=%s#comment-%s') % (
                        thread.get_absolute_url(),
                        page, comment.pk
                    )
                )
    return redirect(('%s#comment-%s') % (thread.get_absolute_url(), comment.pk))
```

and inside `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(
        r'^comment/direct/(?P<pk>[-\d]+)/$',
        find_comment, name='find_comment_page'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the position of the object via

```
position=Comment.objects.filter(created__lt=comment.created).order_by('created').count()
```

Then get the page number via

```
items_per_page=10
page = int(position/items_per_page)
```

Comment: what is different between _position_ and _page_ here?

Comment: `position` is the position of the object in the query set. When you divide it by the no of comments in a single page, you get the page in which the object appears, thats what the `page` variable is for

Comment: Hmm.. I see, I tried with it with different methods, but I found another problem, if has many pages, eg; thousand of pages.. of course it will take a long time... what the best method I should be do? please checkout my latest update...